# Repeats the last input twice

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool keeprunning = true;
    double GPA;
    char parents;
    char major;
    int math;
    int verbal;
    int applications=0;
    int LAaccepted=0;
    int Maccepted=0;
    int L=1, M=2, N=3, Y=4;

    ifstream inFile("stunumbers.txt");

    while (keeprunning)
    {
        if (inFile)
        {
            inFile >> major >> GPA >> math >> verbal >> parents;

            int combined= math+verbal;
            applications +=1;
            cout<<"Acceptance to College by John Fortuna" <<endl <<endl;
            cout<<"Applicant #: " <<applications <<endl;
            cout<<"School = " <<major <<" GPA = " <<GPA <<" math = " 
                <<math <<" verbal = " <<verbal <<" alumnus = " <<parents <<endl;
            if (major == 'L')
            {
                cout<<"You are applying to Liberal Arts College" <<endl;
                if (parents == 'Y')
                {
                    if (1000 <= combined)
                    {
                        if (LAaccepted <=4)
                        {
                            LAaccepted +=1;
                            cout<<"You have been accepted to the Liberal Arts College!!" <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                        }
                        else if (LAaccepted >= 5)
                            cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the Liberal Arts College due to spots full." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                    }
                    else if (1000 > combined)
                        cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the Liberal Arts College due to a low SAT." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                }

                else if (parents == 'N')
                {
                    if (1200 <= combined)
                    {
                        if (LAaccepted <= 4)
                        {
                        LAaccepted +=1;
                        cout<<"You have been accepted to the Liberal Arts College!!" <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                        }
                        else if (LAaccepted >5)
                            cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the Liberal Arts College due to spots full." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                    }
                    else if (1200 > combined)
                        cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the Liberal Arts College due to a low SAT." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                }
            }
            else if (major == 'M')
            {
                cout<<"Applying to Music" <<endl;
                if (500 <= math && 500 <= verbal)
                {
                        if (Maccepted <= 2)
                        {
                            Maccepted +=1;
                            cout<<"You have been accepted to the College of Music!!" <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                        }
                        else if (LAaccepted >= 3)
                            cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the College of Music due to spots full." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                }
                    else if (math <= 500 || 500 <= verbal)
                    {
                        cout<<"You have been denied addmission to the College of Music due to a low SAT." <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl <<endl;
                }
            }       

            else 
                keeprunning = false;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to take data off a file and have it read and tell the person if they have been admitted.  Everything works except for the last data it keeps giving me the last data twice how can I fix this?

Comment: For everyone's sake, please spend the time to create a [Minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Odds are good that you'll find the problem on your own in the process!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the check of whether the reading was successful or not to a line immediately after the line that reads the data.

Instead of

```
  if (inFile)
  {
     inFile >> major >> GPA >> math >> verbal >> parents;
```

Use

```
  inFile >> major >> GPA >> math >> verbal >> parents;
  if (inFile)
  {
```

Comment: Actually, just use `if (inFile >> major >> GPA >> math >> verbal >> parents)`. In English " if reading major,GPA, math... succeeded then"